# How to get same domain invisible IFRAME content in to main page when iframe finishes its process?

Tags: php, javascript, html, iframe

i Wonder how i can create an invisible iframe and get its final content in to main page too not only inside the iframe? (Note. My invisible iframe url is in same domain and is written in php and i can modify it for my requirement).

```
<iframe id ='myframe' src='http://www.mydomain.com/process.php'></iframe>
```

My goal is to show user some sort of loading animation while invisible iframe finishes its process (usually it takes 10 seconds to finish ) and then show the final output in main page and removes the loading animation.

My invisible iframe redirects to another php url(also in same domain) and outputs some data but i want to show this data inside my main page also not only inside invisible iframe. Could you guys tell me how this can done ?

Comment: Because no detail is there, I think you can transfer loaded data to the main page using JavaScript, and then display it here again.

Comment: Why not use AJAX? That's what you're trying to simulate with this iframe.

Comment: akam how i can transfer iframe process.php content to main page? the javascript should be in main page or inside process.php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.roseindia.net/java/pass-value-example/pass-value-from-iframe-parent.shtml) what you looking for? Otherwise I could only think to use `ajax` for this.

Comment: rz-requile that is good example but instead of user clicking submit is it possible to transfer the whole iframe content(html content) in to a Div in main frame ?i dont have textbox in iframe process it is simple html output done by my process.php

Answer (score 1):

Use `ajax` to share state b/w them or you can perform animations in one window and when it finishes, you can open a new window using `window.open();`

I have never tried ajax in this way, but:

```
<frameset cols="25%,*,25%">
  <frame src="frame_a.php">
  <frame src="frame_b.php">
</frameset>
```

When animation on `frame_a.php` finishes, a JavaScript method can use ajax to communicate with `frame_b.php`

That method inside the `<script></script>` on `frame_a.php` will send post or get parameters to `frame_b.php`. Don't worry about loading... it is fast enough if you do not have a lot of resources (css/js files). Moreover, if you do not want the user to wait you can set some default animation on `frame_b.php`.

This is what the method should contain:

```
function share_state_with_frame_b(state) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "frame_b.php",
      data: { d1: "v1" , d2: "v2" }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
      // close frame_a.php
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys for reply . how i can make a ajax call to http://www.mydomain.com/process.php and output its content in main page ?do i need to call ajax once(i dont want to call ajax many times as it will puts lots of load in server side) and wait for its content ?i dont want the user of my page think that page is not working while it waits for ajax content to arrive!